# Permission Denied installing rabl gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to install the spree gem but i am having a little trouble installing the gem. currently i am getting an error when trying to install the rabl(0.13.1) gem. I am getting a permission is denied . Wondering how i can fix this error so i can get back to finish installing spree.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink
```

---

```
Installing rabl 0.13.1
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink -
(fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.json.rabl,
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rabl-0.13.1/fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.xml.rabl)
An error occurred while installing rabl (0.13.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rabl -v '0.13.1'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  spree was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
    spree_backend was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
      spree_api was resolved to 3.4.1, which depends on
        rabl

C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\ruby\pen>gem install rabl -v '0.13.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.json.rabl, C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rabl-0.13.1/fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.xml.rabl)

C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\ruby\pen>gem install
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Please specify at least one gem name (e.g. gem build GEMNAME)

C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\ruby\pen>uby/gems/2.4
'uby' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: use sudo? Or use a local install of ruby via rvm, chruby et al?

Comment: try running the command as an Administrator. on windows use the `runas` command

Comment: If you want to develop in Windows, you can use Vagrant with VirtualBx... life  will be much easier for you!

Answer (score 7):

You can fix it by running your terminal on windows ( "Start Command Prompt with Ruby", "Git Bash" or similar ) as administrator.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone runs into this problem in a Windows environment (windows 10), 
use `start command prompt with ruby` as administrator 
and run `bundle update`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would recommend you to use `bundler` for automatic dependencies resolving.

Regarding your problem, I believe the root cause is here: `Permission denied @ rb_file_s_symlink - (fixtures/ashared/views_rails_3/users/phone_number.json.rabl`

You should check permissions for this file and probably fix them. Because your current user does not have enough rights to access it.

And the last, but not the least, try switching to linux/mac. Windows is really not suitable for productive Ruby developemnt.

Comment: If in Windows a Vagrant + VBox would also do. Even WSL (Windows sub system for Linux) is alright in some of the cases

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem when trying to install the Spree gem on ruby on rails.

This was done on Rails 5.1.4, running Ruby ruby 2.3.3p222

This error occurs when you don't have admin rights.

Firstly, locate cmd and then right click on it and click on 'Run as administrator'.

Log in with the appropiate credentials and then when the cmd pops up, run the command again

> gem install rabl -v '0.13.1'

And it should be successful!

Answer (score 0):

In mac, I am facing similar issue and fixed by answer here: https://nanxiao.me/en/fix-permission-denied-rb_file_s_symlink-error-of-installing-homebrew/

I have pasted the command in case the link stops working.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```